# Simplify equations using list of rules

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a set of equations that I want to simplify using a list of rules:

```
eqns={
I (ρ12'[t]+ρ21'[t])==ω1 (ρ12[t]-ρ21[t])+ω2 (-ρ12[t]+ρ21[t])+Ω23 (-ρ13[t]+ρ31[t])+Ω13 (-ρ23[t]+ρ32[t])+Ω24 (-ρ14[t]+ρ41[t])+Ω14 (-ρ24[t]+ρ42[t]),
I (ρ13'[t]+ρ31'[t])==Ω23 (-ρ12[t]+ρ21[t])+ω1 (ρ13[t]-ρ31[t])+ω3 (-ρ13[t]+ρ31[t])+Ω14 (-ρ34[t]+ρ43[t]),
I (ρ14'[t]+ρ41'[t])==Ω24 (-ρ12[t]+ρ21[t])+ω1 (ρ14[t]-ρ41[t])+ω4 (-ρ14[t]+ρ41[t])+Ω13 (ρ34[t]-ρ43[t]),
I (ρ23'[t]+ρ32'[t])==Ω13 (ρ12[t]-ρ21[t])+ω2 (ρ23[t]-ρ32[t])+ω3 (-ρ23[t]+ρ32[t])+Ω24 (-ρ34[t]+ρ43[t]),
I (ρ24'[t]+ρ42'[t])==Ω14 (ρ12[t]-ρ21[t])+ω2 (ρ24[t]-ρ42[t])+ω4 (-ρ24[t]+ρ42[t])+Ω23 (ρ34[t]-ρ43[t]),
I (ρ34'[t]+ρ43'[t])==Ω14 (ρ13[t]-ρ31[t])+Ω24 (ρ23[t]-ρ32[t])+Ω13 (ρ14[t]-ρ41[t])+Ω23 (ρ24[t]-ρ42[t])+ω3 (ρ34[t]-ρ43[t])+ω4 (-ρ34[t]+ρ43[t]),
I ρ12'[t]-I ρ21'[t]==ω2 (-ρ12[t]-ρ21[t])+ω1 (ρ12[t]+ρ21[t])+Ω23 (-ρ13[t]-ρ31[t])+Ω13 (ρ23[t]+ρ32[t])+Ω24 (-ρ14[t]-ρ41[t])+Ω14 (ρ24[t]+ρ42[t]),
I ρ13'[t]-I ρ31'[t]==Ω23 (-ρ12[t]-ρ21[t])+ω3 (-ρ13[t]-ρ31[t])+ω1 (ρ13[t]+ρ31[t])+Ω13 (-2 ρ11[t]+2 ρ33[t])+Ω14 (ρ34[t]+ρ43[t]),
I ρ14'[t]-I ρ41'[t]==Ω24 (-ρ12[t]-ρ21[t])+ω4 (-ρ14[t]-ρ41[t])+ω1 (ρ14[t]+ρ41[t])+Ω13 (ρ34[t]+ρ43[t])+Ω14 (-2 ρ11[t]+2 ρ44[t]),
I ρ23'[t]-I ρ32'[t]==Ω13 (-ρ12[t]-ρ21[t])+ω3 (-ρ23[t]-ρ32[t])+ω2 (ρ23[t]+ρ32[t])+Ω23 (-2 ρ22[t]+2 ρ33[t])+Ω24 (ρ34[t]+ρ43[t]),
I ρ24'[t]-I ρ42'[t]==Ω14 (-ρ12[t]-ρ21[t])+ω4 (-ρ24[t]-ρ42[t])+ω2 (ρ24[t]+ρ42[t])+Ω23 (ρ34[t]+ρ43[t])+Ω24 (-2 ρ22[t]+2 ρ44[t]),
I ρ34'[t]-I ρ43'[t]==Ω14 (-ρ13[t]-ρ31[t])+Ω24 (-ρ23[t]-ρ32[t])+Ω13 (ρ14[t]+ρ41[t])+Ω23 (ρ24[t]+ρ42[t])+ω4 (-ρ34[t]-ρ43[t])+ω3 (ρ34[t]+ρ43[t]),
-I ρ11'[t]+I ρ22'[t]==Ω13 (ρ13[t]-ρ31[t])+Ω23 (-ρ23[t]+ρ32[t])+Ω14 (ρ14[t]-ρ41[t])+Ω24 (-ρ24[t]+ρ42[t]),
-I ρ22'[t]+I ρ33'[t]==Ω13 (ρ13[t]-ρ31[t])+Ω23 (2 ρ23[t]-2 ρ32[t])+Ω24 (ρ24[t]-ρ42[t]),
-I ρ22'[t]+I ρ44'[t]==Ω23 (ρ23[t]-ρ32[t])+Ω14 (ρ14[t]-ρ41[t])+Ω24 (2 ρ24[t]-2 ρ42[t])
}
```

and the transformation rules are

```
rules={ρ12[t]+ρ21[t]->k1[t],ρ13[t]+ρ31[t]->k2[t],ρ14[t]+ρ41[t]->k3[t],ρ23[t]+ρ32[t]->k4[t],ρ24[t]+ρ42[t]->k5[t],ρ34[t]+ρ43[t]->k6[t],ρ12[t]-ρ21[t]->k7[t],ρ13[t]-ρ31[t]->k8[t],ρ14[t]-ρ41[t]->k9[t],ρ23[t]-ρ32[t]->k10[t],ρ24[t]-ρ42[t]->k11[t],ρ34[t]-ρ43[t]->k12[t],-ρ11[t]+ρ22[t]->k13[t],-ρ22[t]+ρ33[t]->k14[t],-ρ22[t]+ρ44[t]->k15[t],ρ33[t]-ρ11[t]->k13[t]+k14[t],ρ44[t]-ρ11[t]->k13[t]+k15[t]}
```

and its derivative `D[rules,t]`.

I want to simplify the `eqns` so that it is free of `ρ` variables.

I tried something like this but not work

```
ρls = 
 Flatten@Table[
   ToExpression["ρ" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j] <> "[t]"], {i, 
    1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}];
trans[expr_] := expr /. rules /. D[rules, t]
Simplify[eqns, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, trans}, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#1] + 
     If[And @@ Table[FreeQ[#, x], {x, ρls}], 0, 10^3] &)]
```

Comment: Why not try `Eliminate`?

Comment: `Eliminate` seems complicated it a lot rather than simplify it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help others would come up with a more canonic solution, but here is one (brute force) way:

First construct rules that covers both shapes like `a-b->c` and `-a+b->-c`

```
rules1 = rules /. Rule[x_, y_] :> Rule[-x, -y]; 
totRules = Join[rules, rules1, D[rules, t], D[rules1, t]];
```

then transfer equations to lists to avoid simplify moving terms across the `==` sign.

```
transCoff = Transpose[eqns /. x_ == y_ :> {x, y}];
```

Define a function that simplify each sub-expression, especially to transform terms like `a(b*c-b*d)` to `a*b*(c-d)`

```
mysimplify[expr_] := 
 Module[{expr1 = 
    Collect[expr, {\[Omega]1, \[Omega]2, \[Omega]3, \[Omega]4, \
\[CapitalOmega]13, \[CapitalOmega]14, \[CapitalOmega]23, \
\[CapitalOmega]24, I }, Simplify]},
  Head[expr1] @@ Simplify /@ List @@ expr1
  ]
```

replace the rules

```
Apply[Equal, 
 Transpose@
  Map[Collect[#, ToExpression@Table["k" <> ToString@i, {i, 1, 15}], 
     Simplify] &, 
   Map[mysimplify, 
     Simplify[(Collect[#, {\[Omega]1, \[Omega]2, \[Omega]3, \
\[Omega]4, \[CapitalOmega]13, \[CapitalOmega]14, \[CapitalOmega]23, \
\[CapitalOmega]24, I }, Simplify] & /@ transCoff) /. 
       totRules], {2}] /. totRules, {2}], {1}]
```

and get the result free of `rho**`

[image]